# Unable to get text that has no identifier inside pane with pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, pywinauto

I have pane inside pane , identifiers are available till pane inside pane I want to get text.[image]

Identifiers are as
[image]

Is there any way to get text having no identifier inside pane

Comment: By the way, please switch `Inspect.exe` to UI Automation mode from MSAA. It won't help much in this case, but it will show more info definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible using MS UI Automation API (both `Inspect.exe` and pywinauto use it under the hood).

If it's .NET app, it could be possible in far theory by managed DLL injection. I'm aware about only this minimal proof-of-concept: https://github.com/vperevalov/WPFA (not tried yet).